# I am getting data type conversion error while retrieving the data from Firbase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting the error

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int

This is the code which is creating the writing the data in firebase

```
    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
    String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    double price = Double.parseDouble(emailholder.getText().toString().replace("₹", ""));
    double quantityValue = Double.parseDouble(quantity.getText().toString());
    double result = price * quantityValue;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String purl = intent.getStringExtra("purl");


    final HashMap<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
    cartMap.put("productName",nameholder.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("productPrice",emailholder.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("productImage", purl);
    cartMap.put("date",saveCurrentDate);
    cartMap.put("time",saveCurrentTime);
    cartMap.put("quantity",quantity.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("totalPrice",result);

    String currentUserPhoneNumber = Paper.book().read(Prevalent.UserPhoneKey);

    Query query = cartListRef.child(currentUserPhoneNumber).orderByChild("productName").equalTo(nameholder.getText().toString());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String cartKey = snapshot.getKey();
                    int oldQuantity = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("quantity").getValue().toString());
                    int newQuantity = oldQuantity + Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());
                    double oldTotalPrice = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.child("totalPrice").getValue().toString());
                    double newTotalPrice = result + oldTotalPrice;
                    cartListRef.child(currentUserPhoneNumber).child(cartKey).child("quantity").setValue(String.valueOf(newQuantity));
                    cartListRef.child(currentUserPhoneNumber).child(cartKey).child("totalPrice").setValue(String.valueOf(newTotalPrice));
                    Toast.makeText(details.this, "Quantity updated in cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

This is the code of model class which I created for retrieving data:

```
public class Cartmodel {
    private String date;
    private String productImage;
    private String productName;
    private String productPrice;
    private String quantity;
    private String time;
    private int totalPrice;
 
    public Cartmodel() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Cartmodel.class)
    }
 
    public Cartmodel(String date, String productImage, String productName, String productPrice, String quantity, String time, int totalPrice) {
        this.date = date;
        this.productImage = productImage;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.time = time;
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }
  
    public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }
  
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
  
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
  
    public String getProductPrice() {
        String price = this.productPrice.replace("₹", "");
        return price;
    }
  
    public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }
  
    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
  
    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public void setTotalPrice(int totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }
}
```

This is the adapter

```
public class cartAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cartmodel,cartAdapter.viewholder>
{
    public cartAdapter(@androidx.annotation.NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cartmodel> options) {
        super(options);
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Cartmodel cartmodel) {
        holder.pnametext.setText(cartmodel.getProductName());
        holder.quantity.setText("Qty: " + cartmodel.getQuantity());
        holder.totalprice.setText("Total: " + cartmodel.getTotalPrice());
 
 
        Glide.with(holder.img2.getContext())
                .load(cartmodel.getProductImage())
                .into(holder.img2);
    }
 
 
    @androidx.annotation.NonNull
    @Override
    public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@androidx.annotation.NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
 
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_singlero,parent,false);
        return new viewholder(view);
 
    }
 
    public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
 
        public ImageView img2;
        public TextView pnametext;
        public TextView quantity;
        public TextView totalprice;
 
 
        public viewholder(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
 
            img2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img2);
            pnametext=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pnametext);
            quantity=itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            totalprice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalprice);
 
 
 
        }
 
        public View getContext() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Firebase datastructure

```
"Cart List": [
null,
{
  "1676655818423": {
    "date": "Feb 17, 2023",
    "productImage": "https://images.jdmagicbox.com/comp/mumbai/z3/022pxx22.xx22.181204184809.b5z3/catalogue/burger-king-santacruz-east-mumbai-burger-king-3hofjz4vmz.jpg",
    "productName": "Chicken Burger",
    "productPrice": "₹350",
    "quantity": "5",
    "time": "23:13:38 PM",
    "totalPrice": "1750.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data in the database?

Comment: HII @Bart I attached the firebase datastructure